# how to programmatically "click" on html element embedded in asp:literal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an .aspx page with several asp:button controls on it.  There is also an asp:Literal control, which contains an HTML section that displays a "page-turning" view of images, and has the following UI interface that is backed by jquery functions; the details are not necessary to understand the question I pose here. (I had to edit this to put it in a comment, so it would be visible here):

Previous - Next-->

My question is: how can I, via button clicks in the top-level .aspx, how can I invoke the "onclick" operations in the above ?   The end goal is to update (server-side) label.text data on the page whenever "previous" or "next" are clicked.   I have tried adding javascript function calls to the "onclick" to do __doPostBack, first, but then the other javascript doesn't get invoked.   For example: this:

```
<!--<script language="javascript">
        function st(arg) {
          __doPostBack('imagechange', arg);
           }
    </script>
<div><a href="#" class="hdr1" onclick="st(-1); $('.PGFLIP:eq(0)').trigger('previous'); return false;">Previous</a> - <a href="#" class="hdr1" onclick="javascript: st(1); $('.PGFLIP:eq(0)').trigger('next'); return false;">Next</a></div>-->
```

Then, in Page_Load where isPostback=true, I can use 'arg' as needed and update label(s) on the page.
If the 'previous' and 'next' links are clicked, the st(...) function runs, the postback happens, BUT the rest of the onclick logic DOES NOTHING.
I hope this is enough detail; I think there are probably multiple approaches to solve this, but I'm a bit lost at the moment!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to call it from JQuery you can do this.

$('#buttonID').trigger('click');

Comment: do you mean to say that '#buttonID' is that of an asp:button on the page? Hmm, I will try that!

Comment: I added what you suggested to both 'previous' and 'next' "onclick=" actions, but no click event happens on the page for 'buttonID'.  I do note that doing this puts 2 'trigger's in each 'onclick'; I don't recall seeing that done before, FWIW.